# Laravel - Creating an AJAX filter for filtering a SQL database

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

This is something I have tried to do time and time again. I have the following column (named `type`) in my database called `pets`:

```
type 
DOG 
DOG 
CAT 
CAT 
DOG
```

What I am trying to do is to create a filter, so I can choose if I want to display only the dogs, only the cats or both together. This should be done live (using AJAX) - so I don't have to reload the webpage when I choose the filter I want.

I have come up with this for the AJAX request:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active').on('click', function() {
        $value=$(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url  : '{{$petname->pet_code}}',
            data : {'search':$value},
            success:function(data) {
                $('#results-of-ajax-search').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

This unfortunately did not work as intended. I am guessing I was unable to target the necessary value of the chosen filter. I am using this for the front-end part of this question:

```js
$.fn.ulSelect = function() {
  var ul = $(this);

  if (!ul.hasClass('zg-ul-select-type')) {
    ul.addClass('zg-ul-select-type');
  }
  // SVG arrow
  var arrowtype = '<svg id="ul-arrowtype" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><line stroke-width="1" x1="" y1="" x2="" y2="" stroke="#449FDB" opacity=""/><path d="M4.131 8.962c-0.434-0.429-1.134-0.429-1.566 0-0.432 0.427-0.432 1.122 0 1.55l12.653 12.528c0.434 0.429 1.133 0.429 1.566 0l12.653-12.528c0.432-0.429 0.434-1.122 0-1.55s-1.136-0.429-1.566-0.002l-11.87 11.426-11.869-11.424z" fill="#111"/></svg>';
  $('li:first-of-type', this).addClass('active').append(arrowtype);
  $(this).on('click', 'li', function(event) {

    // Remove div#selected if it exists
    if ($('#selected--zg-ul-select-type').length) {
      $('#selected--zg-ul-select-type').remove();
    }
    ul.before('<div id="selected--zg-ul-select-type">');
    var selected = $('#selected--zg-ul-select-type');
    $('li #ul-arrowtype', ul).remove();
    ul.toggleClass('active');
    ul.children().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    var selectedText = $(this).text();
    if (ul.hasClass('active')) {
      selected.text(selectedText).addClass('active').append(arrowtype);
    } else {
      selected.text('').removeClass('active');
      $('li.active', ul).append(arrowtype);
    }
  });
  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($('ul.zg-ul-select-type').length) {
      if (!$('ul.zg-ul-select-type').has(event.target).length == 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        $('ul.zg-ul-select-type').removeClass('active');
        $('#selected--zg-ul-select-type').removeClass('active').text('');
        $('#ul-arrowtype').remove();
        $('ul.zg-ul-select-type li.active').append(arrowtype);
      }
    }
  });
};
$('#be-select-type').ulSelect();
```

```css
ul.zg-ul-select-type {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type li {
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type li.active {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type.active li {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type.active li:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type.active li.active:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#selected--zg-ul-select-type {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#selected--zg-ul-select-type.active {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="data-control">
  <ul id="be-select-type" tabindex="0">
 <li><span class="filter-text" id="filter-type-reset">Filter by Type</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter-text" id="filter-type-cat">Dog</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter-text" id="filter-type-dog">Cat</span></li>
</ul>
</span>
```

If you run that code, it creates the front-end select list and adds a class of `active` to the selected value in the list.

For the Laravel backend controller, I am guessing you would have to add a `where` statement to a `DB` query and use an `=` to get and filter the value of the `$request`.

Basically, the correct answer for this question would be to create an AJAX request to my controller.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first block of code, when you try to get li element's "value" you must use .text() - if you want to get just text or .html() - if you want to get inner HTML :

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('li.active').on('click', function() {
        var $value=$(this).text();
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url  : '{{$petname->pet_code}}',
            data : {'search':$value},
            success:function(data) {
                $('#results-of-ajax-search').html(data);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

**EDITED:**

As a quick fix for ur problem, u can remove above block of code and use ur front-end part code with changes. A have added a snippet :

```js
$(function(){

$.fn.ulSelect = function() {
  var ul = $(this);

  if (!ul.hasClass('zg-ul-select-type')) {
    ul.addClass('zg-ul-select-type');
  }
  // SVG arrow
  var arrowtype = '<svg id="ul-arrowtype" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" version="1.1" width="10" height="10" viewBox="0 0 32 32"><line stroke-width="1" x1="" y1="" x2="" y2="" stroke="#449FDB" opacity=""/><path d="M4.131 8.962c-0.434-0.429-1.134-0.429-1.566 0-0.432 0.427-0.432 1.122 0 1.55l12.653 12.528c0.434 0.429 1.133 0.429 1.566 0l12.653-12.528c0.432-0.429 0.434-1.122 0-1.55s-1.136-0.429-1.566-0.002l-11.87 11.426-11.869-11.424z" fill="#111"/></svg>';
  $('li:first-of-type', this).addClass('active').append(arrowtype);


  $(this).on('click', 'li', function(event) {

    // Remove div#selected if it exists
    if ($('#selected--zg-ul-select-type').length) {
      $('#selected--zg-ul-select-type').remove();
    }
    ul.before('<div id="selected--zg-ul-select-type">');
    var selected = $('#selected--zg-ul-select-type');
    $('li #ul-arrowtype', ul).remove();
    ul.toggleClass('active');
    ul.children().removeClass('active');
    $(this).toggleClass('active');

    var selectedText = $(this).text();
    if (ul.hasClass('active')) {
      selected.text(selectedText).addClass('active').append(arrowtype);
    } else {
      selected.text('').removeClass('active');
      $('li.active', ul).append(arrowtype);
      /* AJAX GET REQUEST */
      if(!$(this).is('li:first-of-type')){
        $.ajax({
            type : 'get',
            url  : '{{$petname->pet_code}}',
            data : {'search':selectedText},
            success:function(data) {
                $('#results-of-ajax-search').html(data);
            }
        });
      }
      /* AJAX GET REQUEST ENDS */
    }

  });

  $(document).on('click', function(event) {
    if ($('ul.zg-ul-select-type').length) {
      if (!$('ul.zg-ul-select-type').has(event.target).length == 0) {
        return;
      } else {
        $('ul.zg-ul-select-type').removeClass('active');
        $('#selected--zg-ul-select-type').removeClass('active').text('');
        $('#ul-arrowtype').remove();
        $('ul.zg-ul-select-type li.active').append(arrowtype);
      }
    }
  });

};
$('#be-select-type').ulSelect();

});
```

```css
ul.zg-ul-select-type {
  position: relative;
  outline: none;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0 auto;
  width: 250px;
  border-radius: 3px;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  cursor: pointer;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: auto;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type li {
  outline: none;
  text-align: left;
  background-color: #fff;
  display: none;
  padding: 15px;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type li.active {
  align-items: center;
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type.active li {
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  box-shadow: none;
  display: block;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type.active li:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

ul.zg-ul-select-type.active li.active:hover {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

#selected--zg-ul-select-type {
  outline: none;
  background-color: #fff;
  margin: 0 auto;
  text-align: center;
  width: 250px;
  align-items: center;
  box-sizing: border-box;
  color: #111;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-between;
}

#selected--zg-ul-select-type.active {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  border-radius: 3px;
  padding: 15px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="data-control">
  <ul id="be-select-type" tabindex="0">
 <li><span class="filter-text" id="filter-type-reset">Filter by Type</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter-text" id="filter-type-cat">Dog</span></li>
    <li><span class="filter-text" id="filter-type-dog">Cat</span></li>
</ul>
</span>
```